# Hide div in jqueryag

Tags: jquery

When i click on a tag then it is display and animate respective div. Now I want that if i click again on same a tag and if its respective div is left 20 then it should left -30. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckDHz/2/)

**jQuery**

```
$('li').click(function(e){
   var li= $(this).index()
var off= $(this).offset().top;
    $('div').each(function(){
        $(this).animate({left:'-30px',top:off},500, function(){
         $('div').eq(li).animate({left:'20px',top:off},500)
        })
    })    


})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct you just dont want to use the animation you are doing after you have moved the div -30px to the left?

```
$('li').click(function(e){
    var li = $(this);
    var index = li.index()
    var topOffset = li.offset().top;
    var isOpen = li.toggleClass('open').hasClass('open');
    li.siblings().removeClass('open');
    $('div').each(function(){
        $(this).animate({ left: '-30px', top: topOffset }, 500, function(){
            if(isOpen) {
                $('div').eq(index).animate({ left: '20px', top: topOffset}, 500);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ckDHz/3/